# What is the Compiler Status in magento?

Tags: magento, compiler-construction, compilation

What is Compiler Status magento? Should it be enable or disabled? 
Is Compilation Mode something different than compiler status?
Couldn't find this in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compilation helps to make your website faster. If you decide to use it, you need to remember to turn it off before making any changes to your modules and to recompile all before enabling it again.
Here's the best resource I found on this subject:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path

Comment: thanks! So right now my Compiler Status:Disabled and 
Compilation State:Not Compiled. Should I be enabling the status since my store is ready to go live? Should I switch my compilation state?

Comment: It is not necessary to have the compiler enabled and in some cases it causes more troubles than profit. It's designed to cure long classes lookups so if you don't have many modules and overwrites then it's sometimes better to leave it disabled. I don't know how your Magento website has been built so probably best is to test how your particular shop is performing with Compilation being turned on and turned off and then decide whether it's useful in your case. But  you need to remember to turn it off before making any changes to your modules and recompile if you want to turn it back on again.

Comment: :@ yes always forgetting to do that could easily becomes the headache.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler should be set to on for Live sites but during development it should be switched off.

Explanation : When compiler is switched on then magento will create copies of all class files and place those files in inlcudes/src folder so when PHP is executed it does not need to go into too many folders this will result in time being saved during execution.

When We are in development mode we will edit files as per standard magento code.But If compiler is on those files are not used for execution but files in includes/src are executed so no changes will be effective.Hence you need to switch compiler on when in development mode.